# Create multiple "sub-tables" from one large table in a loop in Python

Tags: python

I've tried searching for an example of how I might solve this but can't seem to find a specific example that matches my needs.

I'm trying to create multiple separate dataframes (up to 80 - depending on the data that I have) from one large dataframe (using the value in a column s the "grouper". I have records for multiple patient "types" (where patient type is a column variable) and want to create separate dataframes for each of these types.

The reason I want to do this is I want to plot separate kaplan meier survival curves for each of these dataframes. I've tried doing this using subplots - but there are too many different patient types to do in a series of sub-plots (the subplots end up looking too small).

I'm new to Python so apologies if this is a silly question...and thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: Could [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) be what you are searching?

Comment: Also tell us if is pandas dataframe, MySQL database, or whatever.